# Python's print function in a class

Tags: python, python-2.x

I can't execute `print` function in the class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

class MyClass:
    def print(self):
        print 'MyClass'

a = MyClass()
a.print()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
File "./start.py", line 9
    a.print()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: @erip It could be (in Python 2).

Comment: print is a reserved word (at least in python2)

Comment: What version of Python 2 are you using?

Comment: That error is surprising. I'd have expected Python2 to have complained at `def print(self)`, as `print` is a reserved word, and Python3 to have complained at `print 'MyClass'` as in Python3 `print` is a function.

Comment: I checked: it's 2.7.12.

Comment: Anyone have a 2.7.12 interpreter laying around to test the above on it? I just checked on a 2.6.9 interpreter, and the error comes at the function definition... it would be weird if it was a bug only for 2.7.12, but not 2.6.9 or 2.7.13

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I just installed 2.7.12 (aside: [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) rocks) and I get syntax error on line 5, `def print(self):`, as expected. I don't believe that OP's code gets OP's error message.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know but the error occurs in `print` definition today (`def print(self):`). Yesterday the error was as I said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python 2, `print` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). It can only be used for its intended purpose. I can't be the name of a variable or a function.

In Python 3, `print` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), not a keyword. So methods, for example, can have the name `print`.

If you are using Python 2 and want to override its default behavior, you can import Python 3's behavior from [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future):

```
from __future__ import print_function
class MyClass:
    def print(self):
        print ('MyClass')

a = MyClass()
a.print()
```

Comment: On Python 3.5.2, it works even without `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: Yes. Hopefully my recent edit makes that more clear.

Answer (score 8):

You are using Python 2 (which you really shouldn't, unless you have a very good reason).

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, so `print` is actually a reserved word. Indeed, a SyntaxError *should* have been thrown when you tried to define a function with the name `print`, i.e.:

```
In [1]: class MyClass:
   ...:     def print(self):
   ...:         print 'MyClass'
   ...:
   ...: a = MyClass()
   ...: a.print()
  File "<ipython-input-1-15822827e600>", line 2
    def print(self):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, I'm curious as to what exact version of Python 2 you are using. the above output was from a Python 2.7.13 session...

So note, in Python 3:

```
>>> class A:
...    def print(self):
...       print('A')
...
>>> A().print()
A
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code on Python 3 like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def print(self):
        print ('MyClass')

a = MyClass()
a.print()
```

It worked !!

Output:

```
MyClass
```

Running your code as is gives me Syntax Error. Because of missing parenthesis in print. Also, note that print is a reserved keyword in Python 2 but a built-in-function in Python 3.